# Get iteration number within a nested loop

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, unix, for-loop

For a nested loop that uses two or more arrays, e.g.

```
A=(0.1 0.2)
B=(2 4 6)

AB=$((${#A[@]}*${#B[@]})) # total number of iterations (length of A * length of B)

for a in ${A[*]}; do
  for b in ${B[*]}; do

    $(($a+$b)) # task using each combination of A and B
    echo ? # show number of the iteration (i.e. 1 to length of AB)

  done
done
```

What is the best way to get the number of the iteration, as shown above using `echo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with a simple counter that is incremented inside the inner loop:

```
i=0
for a in "${A[@]}"; do
  for b in "${B[@]}"; do
    ((i++))
    printf "Iteration: $i\n"
    : your code
  done
done
```

This would make sense if all the logic is inside the inner-most loop and if we consider the execution of inner-most loop as one iteration.

---

Note that you need double quotes around array reference to prevent word splitting and globbing.  Also, I think you need `array[@]` rather than `array[*]` as long as you want each element separately and not a concatenated version of all elements.

Comment: Thanks. This method works well for this example. However, if I start the script with `set -e` (exit on error), then nothing is printed. While obviously not critical, is this indicating that there is an imperfection with this code?

Comment: @user3743235 It works with `set -e` if you start at `i=1` and use `((++i))`. Why is not clear to me, though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example given and the method suggested by @codeforester, this is what worked for me (with `set -e` included near the start of the script).

```
i=1
for a in ${A[*]}; do
  for b in ${B[*]}; do
    I=$((i++))
    echo "Iteration: $I"
    echo "Combination: $a $b" # show combination of A and B elements
    # task code
  done
done
```

In this example, `array[*]` without the double quotes produced the desired result, using each element separately within the loop to produce unique combinations of `A` and `B` values, while finding each iteration number within the nested loop.

Comment: Although this might work for your case, it has several problems that are already pointed out by @codeforester.